# Trying to use $http in my Service and getting 'Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building a web app with Angular and slowly transitioning out blocks of jQuery code into Angular code. Basically I'm working on a modal for multiple products. When a button is `ng-clicked` I want to load the corresponding HTML into the modal.

As I was converting over my Ajax code to what you see below, I got stuck when trying to use $http to pull in the HTML I need. You can see my old jQuery code `.load()` commented out.

> Error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=*
>
> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

```
// Controller for Training (Contains ng-click to start open Modal service)
app.controller('CoursesController', [
    '$scope',
    'courseModal', function ($scope, courseModal) {

        this.openModal = function(course) {
            courseModal.openModal(course);
        }
    }
]);



/*
SERVICE : for Course Modals
*/

(function() {

var app = angular.module('course-modal', []);

//app.service('courseModal', function ($scope, $http) {
app.service('courseModal', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    this.openModal = function(course_name) {
        $('.overlay').show();

        $scope.data = {};

        $http.get("components/training/modals/courses/"+course_name+".html").
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });

        //   $('.course_modal').load("components/training/modals/courses/"+course_name+".html");

            $('.course_modal').fadeIn('fast');

            $('.close_modal').unbind('click').bind("click", function (event) {
                $('.course_modal').hide();
                $('.course_modal').empty();
                $('.overlay').hide();           
            });
        }
    }]);

})();
```

Do you see where I'm going wrong above? What do I need to inject to get the $http to work correctly?

Strange thing is, for some reason I'm able to not have errors here in this Plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/8f0Qp8sU3ZKFIftON8jP

Comment: Is that the JS error you're getting? When I've seen similar errors, it usually tells me which provider isn't found.

Comment: There is no `$scope` available to be injected into a service.. :) And sorry but the service you have is really bad.. No separation of concerns..

Comment: True! You might consider using a directive for this, seeing as how there's a lot of DOM interaction.

Comment: @RyanKinal ah ok, still getting my head around Angular, I know `Directives` are for loading stuff into the page, would make sense to put the DOM stuff in there too. Just thought that Services are for some functions like my `courseModal`

Comment: I'd probably have a `courseModal` directive, which can take some arguments such as `courseName`. In the template, it might look like this: `<div course-modal course-name="whatever"></div>`. Then the template would include all of your data, as well as, perhaps, a close button that looks like this: `<button ng-click="closeModal()">`. Your directive's scope would have to include `closeModal` of course.

Comment: @PSL I updated the code above to inject $http, I forgot that... however still getting the same error :(

Comment: @LeonGaban As i said before you cannot inject `$scope` into a service there is no scope provider and it does not make sense as well. Call the service method from controller chain through and get the data and set it on the scope from the controller.\

Comment: Any examples? I'm googling trying to find a similar function, where a controller calls a service to load in HTML. Perhaps I should post a new question with that as a title, how to use a service to load in HTML into a directive.

Comment: Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/8f0Qp8sU3ZKFIftON8jP

Comment: your service shouldn't be showing and hiding html, it should instead be handling some form of data. Your controller should be collecting data from the service that the template can then present. Showing and hiding the modal should be done through a modal module that then presents the result back to the controller, which then makes the data available to the template and/or sends it to the service. I don't think you need a directive for this.

Comment: @KevinB so you are saying use 2 controllers for this? I was reading that you want Controllers to be as small as possible, and moving all function code into services :( but ok I'll try that next, good thing is I figured it out.. not sure still what was wrong, just redid the code in plunkr and it works

Comment: The modal controller could be re-used anywhere else you need a modal, you would just swap out the template for each use case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just recoded everything in Plunkr, and now no errors in my app, go figure...

http://plnkr.co/edit/8f0Qp8sU3ZKFIftON8jP

```
/*
SERVICE : for Course Modals
*/
(function() {

var app = angular.module('course-modal', []);

app.service('courseModal', function ($http) {

    this.openModal = function(course_name) {

        // console.log(course_name);
        // alert(course_name);

        $http.get(course_name+".html").
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                document.getElementById("load_html_here").innerHTML=data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
        }
    });

})();
```

Comment: I mean, sure, it works, but it's wrong. you should never need to access the dom from a service..

Comment: I'll change it to a controller in plunkr and see if it works real quick

Comment: Doing it in a controller is no better.

Comment: Eh, maybe i'm wrong. Apparently it's common to create modals using a service (which involves creating the modal html and injecting it into the dom)

Comment: Here's a few examples: https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js

Comment: cool I did get it to work, however it seems to work best with default Bootstrap modals. I also do custom ones right now, and my service is way less code that that one.